# How to get dynamic loaded HTML in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, alamofire

I can use Alamofire to return the HTML of a page, but some div's content is empty.
If I open chrome's developer console I can see them in ELements tab rather than Source tab.
How can I get those contents in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Look this method :
`+ stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:))

```
//the content url
let urlString = "https://google.com"
guard let theURL = URL(string: urlString) else {
    print("Error: \(urlString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
    return
}

do {
    let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: theURL, encoding: .ascii)
    print("html : \(myHTMLString)")
} catch let error {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```